# How to copy an array from a function to an array in the class in Swift?

Tags: arrays, xcode, swift, xcode6, nsarray

I have an array in a function. Look below.

```
    var HeadlinesString:NSString = Headlines["text"] as NSString
    var headlinesArray: NSArray = HeadlinesString.componentsSeparatedByString("\n") as NSArray
```

I also have an empty array inside the class. Look below

```
var headlinesLabels: NSArray = NSArray ()
```

I want to copy the headlinesArray to the headlinesLabels so I can use the array in another function. How can I do this? Should I copy the headlinesArray to the headlinesLabels?
Is there a better way to do it?

I am not sure what to do and how to do it. All suggestions welcomed.

Thanks

Comment: At the risk of sounding glib – if you were using `Array` instead of `NSArray` this would be a lot less of a concern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got different possibilities. First you can add a return-value to your function and return your string-array.

```
func yourFunction()->[String]{
    var headlinesString:String = Headlines["text"] as String
    var headlinesArray:[String] = headlinesString.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
    return headlinesArray
}

var headLinesLabels = yourFunction()
```

Or you can just set the value of your `headLinesLabels` in the function itself:

```
func yourFunction(){
    var headlinesString:String = Headlines["text"] as String
    var headlinesArray:[String] = headlinesString.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
    headLinesLabels = headLinesArray   
}
```

That way you don't need to return a value but you set it right in your function. But I would recommend to use the first possibility.

As you maybe noticed, I've edited your existing code a bit. First you should use `String` instead of `NSString` if you are using Swift.

Also variable-names should always be camelCase. So change `HeadlinesString` to `headlinesString`.

Also you don't need to cast your objects you receive from the `componentsSeparatedByString` method into an NSArray, but you can use `[String]` to cast it to an array with `String` elements. The same with the `headLinesLabels` variable. Just initialize it like that:

```
var headlinesLabels:[String]!
```

That way, Swift knows that this array should contain `String` elements and you can set it at anytime later like that:

```
 headlinesLabels = /*yourStringArray*/
```

Comment: Thanks for your great reply. I am still having trouble. When I println the headlinesArray and the headlinesLabels they are different. headlinesArray = [Family Fun Day Postponed due to Wet Weather]
[Students Qualify for Little Athletics State Championships]
with 48 other elements. headlinesLabels = [Students Qualify for Little Athletics State Championships]
[Students Qualify for Little Athletics State Championships] with 5 of the same elements. What should I do?

Comment: That shouldn't be the case if you copy it. I would recommend you to post another question. Because this question is solved and your problem seems to be different.

Comment: But the headlinesLabels is different from the headlinesArray. Would you mind having a look at the Xcode project?

Comment: Sorry for being annoying but I worked it out. The headlinesLabels needs to be NSMutableArray. To add the headlinesArray to the headlinesLabels use             headlinesLabels.addObjectsFromArray(headlinesArray). Thanks for your in-depth reply again. :)

Comment: You're welcome. Could you please accept my answer if that resolved you problem so that other people can find the answer easier? :)

Comment: Yes I just did. Sorry I didn't do that right away. :)